# Is there a way to indicate that a method will never return?

Tags: c#

Assuming we have the following (very basic code)

```
public int Foo()
{
    while (true)
    {

    }
    // No "return 0" etc. needed here.
}
```

the compiler can understand that this method will never return, and therefore displays a warning and also it **does not require the method to have a `return` statement.**

---

If we have the case

```
public void WontExit()
{
    while (true)
    {

    }
}

public int Foo()
{
    this.WontExit();
    return default(int); // This is needed here.
}
```

a `return` statement is needed, because the compiler can seemingly not foresee that it will never be reached.

---

- Why does the compiler allow for omitting the `return` statement in the first case? Why doesn't it also require a `return` statement? (What are the internals here?)
- Is there any way to indicate the compiler (or reachability analysis) that in the second case, the `return` code path will also never be reached?

Comment: Why would `this.WontExit()` not exit in typical operation? Is this absolutely guaranteed?

Comment: As an aside, the given code *can* exit; ie via exception

Comment: In the actual code it is absolutely guaranteed, because it will `throw` on all code paths.

Comment: I agree: it's possible for there to be a `return` statement inside that `while` loop which could exit the function, so it would be difficult for the compiler to guarantee that it would always run infinitely.

Comment: @JackBrown you're right, that's why I wondered if there maybe was something like `[[noreturn]]` in C++, which can be used for exactly those cases when the programmer knows that the code will never return.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Why does the compiler allow for omitting the return statement in the first case?

Because the final `}` is unreachable. That's the condition that the compiler prevents (and that's in the specification): ever being able to reach the end of a non-void method.

> Is there any way to indicate the compiler (or reachability analysis) that in the second case, the return statement will also never be reached?

No, unfortunately. There are various times that would be useful (where it would be defined as "this method can never return *normally*, i.e. without throwing an exception"), but there's no C# feature for it. I believe Eric Lippert blogged about this at some point... will try to find the article.

Comment: You're probably thinking of [this one](https://ericlippert.com/2011/02/21/never-say-never-part-one/), which is linked in the comments of the dupe question.

Comment: @JeroenMostert: The end of it, yes - but I thought there was another one with more detail. Oh well. I'll leave this answer here despite it being a duplicate; in particular the first part is slightly different.

Comment: You might be thinking of a similar article I wrote for the Coverity blog which has since been taken down.

Comment: @EricLippert: Let's assume that's the one I was thinking of, as it's plausible and avoids me having to research any further :)